# What does the product <basis vector times the underlying field> represent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am confronted with the following definition:

> Let $K$ be a field and $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ the standard basis of the $K$ vector space $K^n$.
>
> For $1\leq i\leq n$ let $V_i=Ke_1+Ke_2+\dots+Ke_n$.

For given $0<m<n$ let
$$P=\{~g\in GL_n(k)~|~g(V_m)=V_m~\}$$

---

The part of the definition I don't understand is highlighted, the rest might use as clarification.

So what does $Ke_1$ mean? (Side question: how does picking a different $i$ make a difference?)

Comment: I think the definition of $V_i$ should be $V_i = Ke_1 + \ldots + Ke_i$.

Comment: @McFry Something like that, yeah. But the professor usually doesn't make mistakes :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Ke_1 = \{ke_1 \mid k \in K\}$ is the set of all multiples of $e_1$, and for two sets $A$ and $B$ of vectors, $A + B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$ denotes the elementwise sum.

So $Ke_1 + \ldots Ke_i = \{k_1e_1 + \ldots + k_ie_i \mid k_1, \ldots, k_i \in K\}$, which is the set of all possible vectors you can represent as sums of multiples of $e_1, \ldots,  e_i$ (the set of all *linear combinations* of $e_1, \ldots, e_i$).

Answer (score 2):

$Ke_1$ usually denotes the set
$$
\{ke_1\mid k\in K\}
$$This set also goes by $\operatorname{span}(e_1)$, or more specifically, $\operatorname{span}_K(e_1)$.